# setting node process.env when running express.js

Tags: node.js, express

i have following server.js file i want to specyfy PORT WHEN running express.js through cmd
something like

```
PORT=4000 node server.js
```

but when i do i get the error

```
'PORT=4000' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

i have also tried to use SET

```
SET PORT=4000
```

but it doesn't  work

```
const express = require('express' );
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
    const path=require('path');
    var port=process.env.PORT || 53000

    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname)+'/index.html');
    });

    app.listen(port);
```

Comment: I assume because I see "process.env.PORT" that you could set that in your webpack (if using webpack)?

Comment: Where's the code where you try to set the PORT environment variable that generates an error?  I don't see any code that attempts to do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 , i set it when i want to run server.js via command line PORT=4000 node server.js

Comment: Please show the exact command line you're attempting to run and describe what OS and command shell you're running it on.  As it stands how, your question doesn't contain enough information for anyone to know what you're currently doing or what the environment is.  The express code you show is pretty much irrelevant to the problem except to confirm that you're trying to read the environment variable.  Setting the environment variable before running your node program is an OS and command shell issue, not a node.js code issue.

Comment: In the Windows cmd shell, you would put `set PORT=4000` on one line and hit return to execute it and then put `node server.js` on the next line and hit return to execute it.  Or, you could create a batch file to do both lines for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think he wants to set the environment variable only for the duration of the command. Would `set PORT=4000` on its own line set it for the entire system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different shells have different syntax for this. Try:

Windows cmd: `cmd /C "set PORT=4000 && node script.js"`

Bash: `PORT=4000 bash -c 'node script.js'`

Fish: `env PORT=4000 node script.js`

Are you on Windows command prompt?

Comment: thanks , actually the issue was with powershell , i was running the set port=4000 from powershell .

Comment: What's the correct syntax in powershell? Feel free to edit this answer and add that if it helps others.